# java.lang.ClassCastException on switching fragments

Tags: android

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (getActivity() == null)
        return;

    ClassA pm = (ClassA) getActivity();
    pm.switchContent(fragment);
}
```

I am trying to `switch fragments` from ClassB, i am getting this exception when i try to do. I am trying to call the fragments of `Class A` Activity.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.ClassB cannot be cast to
>   com.test.ClassA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `instanceof` for checking `getActivity()` type before casting it to  `ClassA` or `ClassB`. try it as :

```
if (getActivity() instanceof ClassA) {
  ClassA pm = (ClassA) getActivity();
  pm.switchContent(fragment);
 } 
 else if (getActivity() instanceof ClassB) {
  ClassB pm = (ClassB) getActivity();
  pm.switchContent(fragment);
}
```

Comment: @Kevin : plz check [this example](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/fragments/ColorMenuFragment.java) for more help because currently you are trying to cast ClassB context to ClassA

Comment: I am using that example, but i am just thinking on if i am in ClassB context... then the fragments of Class A can never be called Being as Class A context... when we are in Class B